# is there a way to know the index of the current cell in an excel named range?

Tags: excel

I have a formula in a range A that points to a cell in range B.

The next cell in range A uses the same formula and uses the next cell in the range B.

Now I use

```
=SUM(....  D27 .....)
```

but instead I want to use something like

```
=SUM(.... VALUE(RANGEB(INDEX=CURRENT_CELL.RANGEA.INDEX) ....)
```

This way I have the very same formula everywhere in range A and the index changes on its own.

At the moment, the next cell in range A would be

```
=SUM(....  E27 .....)
```

which is shorter but meaningless when reading the formula and harder to maintain as each cell has a different formula.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using range names, e.g. `RangeA` and `RangeB`, and assuming `RangeA` and `RangeB` have the same size and shape, you would put this into a `RangeA` cell:

```
=INDEX(RangeB,ROW()-ROW(RangeA)+1,COLUMN()-COLUMN(RangeA)+1)
```

If you don't use range names and substitute `RangeA` and `RangeB` with actual addresses, make sure you use absolute addresses (with `$`s).